# How to specify djangorecipe version

Tags: django, buildout

as I see, djangorecipe 1.6 remove support of fcgi.
It is possible in buildout to specify to use version 1.5 in order to be able to use fcgi ?

thanks

Comment: I think the right way would be to use pip to remove 1.6 and install 1.5..

Comment: @mariodev: no. Buildout is used instead of pip.

Comment: Regarding not supporting fcgi: `bin/django runfcgi` is still there, it is just the special script that got removed. Some django internal API changes made it too much work to retain it (for a feature that is going to be deprecated anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, pin the version in a `[versions]` section:

```
[buildout]
# other options

versions = versions

[versions]
djangorecipe = 1.5
```

It is generally a good idea to pin versions, and set `allow-picked-versions = false` in the `[buildout]` section to force an error for any egg you *didn't* yet pin.